# Google Apps Script Webapp async loading

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am writing a webapp using Google Apps Script.

To reduce loading times I let `doGet(e)` load a small file with some javascript to asynchronously load other JS and CSS.

Loading external resources works fine of course:

```
<head>
  <!-- loading external resources works fine of course -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.c[...]/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.clou[...].1/jquery-ui.min.css">
</head>
```

But from what I know this cannot be done with code inside my apps script project because I cannot provide a direct link to the file.
That's why I add a little `<script>`:

```
function loadScript(filePath) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(returnedValueFromGAS) {
    $('body').append(returnedValueFromGAS);
  }).loadScript(filePath);

  loadScript('someScriptFilepath');
  loadScript('someStyleFilepath')
}
```

In this manner I add `<script>` and `<style>` tags to my HTML.
And I would like to have not one callback for every loaded file, but one callback when all my (script-)files are loaded.

This works fine so far with one major drawback:
The [Window-Load-Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) is not of any use anymore.

How can I load JS and CSS files in the `<head>` like I would do in other environments so that the `load-event` still is of use for me?

Comment: `of any use anymore.` Why not?

Comment: Because the event fires after my tiny document has loaded but not any of my JS or CSS which is loaded by my JS.

Comment: Could you give a specific example of what you're trying to do? Why not include it in head? If not, how are you loading? If you're loading in script tags, `load` event will still fire from that object, which you can listen to. If you're loading through `google.script.run`,`successHandler` will act as a callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And I would like to have not one callback for every loaded file, but one callback when all my (script-)files are loaded.

#### Issue/Solution:

- The script is calling server functions one by one, instead of one after another(or one inside another). You should nest callbacks('Callback hell') or use promises/async/await.

#### Snippet:

```
/**
 * Create a promise around old callback api
 * @param {String} func The server function to call
 * @param {Object} args The arguments to the server function 
 * @return Promise 
 */
const GSR = (func,...args) => 
  new Promise((resolve,reject)=>
    google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(resolve)
        .withFailureHandler(reject)[func](...args)
  );

const bodyAppend = function(returnedValueFromGAS) {
    $('body').append(returnedValueFromGAS);
}

//call GSR and append 
const GSRa = (func, ...args) => 
    GSR(func, ...args)
      .then(bodyAppend)
      .catch(e=>console.error(e.message));

function loadScriptClient() {//modified
  //Can also use async/await here
  Promise.all([GSRa('loadScript','someScriptFilepath'), GSRa('loadScript','someStyleFilepath')])
    .then(/*All Files loaded and appended at this point; Provide a final callback function here*/)
    .catch(e=>console.error(e.message));
}
```

#### References:

- [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)
- [Promises#All](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)