# How to access location.hash globally in google app scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, url, web-applications

I need to store the location.hash as a key to modify my google spreadsheets database. Unfortunately, console.log() always shows undefined. Is there another way to access the value?

```
let global_id_str;
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
   
       google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
       global_id_str = location.hash;
       document.getElementById("Item").textContent =global_id_str;
     });
     search();
  });
```

I have tried calling using a separate function or just using console.log(). it still gives "undefined". I have also tried using getElementById to store the textContent in a varibale but that is also undefined.

```
  function search(){
   console.log('here',global_id_str);
   var returnedResults = global_id_str === "" ? [] : data.filter(function(r){
        return searchWords.every(function(word){
        return [0].some(function(colIndex){
          return r[colIndex].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(word) !== -1
          });
        });
        
       });
        
  }
```

This has to be a problem particular to GAS?

Comment: Your first code block is correctly getting the hash. It works for me. Are you providing a valid hash in the URL? (e.g. https://script.google.com/macros/s/ID/dev#tag)

Comment: @Diego Yes! I am not sure if it is an issue with the function or chrome console but infact my HTML updates accordingly. However when I do console.log(global_id_str); it goves me undefined. Do you think this has anything to do with accessing the global_id_str as a global variable? What would be another way of storing the "tag" as an ID to perform CRUD?

Comment: I don't know where you're calling `console.log(global_id_str)`. You're declaring it with the block-scoped [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), so it's likely that it's simply no longer in scope when you try logging it. Try updating `search()` to take the value as an argument then actually passing it the value...?

Answer (score 1):

`google.script.url.getLocation` is a asynchronous  function. By the time, `location.hash` is set to `global_id_str`, `search` would have already finished running.

#### Solution(s):

- Move `search` into the callback:

```
let global_id_str;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
    global_id_str = location.hash;
    search(); //moved inside callback
    document.getElementById('Item').textContent = global_id_str;
  });
  // search();
});
```

- OR Use promises/async-await. See

  - [Google Apps Script Webapp async loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57472493)
  - [Using Javascript async & await with google.script.url.getLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63531403/using-javascri)

Answer (score 1):

```js
       ////////////////////////////  set hash & parameter global variable  //////////////////////////////////////////////
      

      var hash,option,options;
      
      google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
      var search=location.parameter;
      var search2=location.parameters;
      var ghash=location.hash;
      alert(ghash)
      alocation(ghash,search,search2);
      cform(search)
      });
     function alocation(ghash,search,search2){hash=ghash;option=search;options=search2;}
///////////////////// result ////////////////////
// http://www.example.com?n=1&name=muhammad(sm)&n=2#headingAnchor
hash="headingAnchor"
option.name="muhammad(sm)"
option.n="1"
options.n[0]="1"
optons.n[1]="2"
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. When answering questions, please explain as to why you think that your code snippet solves the OP's problem. For more info, check here: [answer]